# How to get count of the sql search query?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datamapper, codeigniter-datamapper

How to get count of the sql search query

```
$u = new user();

$sql = "SELECT a.id FROM `accounts` AS a LEFT JOIN `users` AS u ON a.id = u.id WHERE a.id IS NOT NULL ";

$gender = $this->input->post('gender');

if($gender != NULL)
{
  $sql .= "AND u.gender = '".$gender."' ";
}

$u->query($sql);
```

How to get count of the query results in `$u->query($sql);` .I need to set a validation on it. If the query results count is 0 , i need to set a message. Im using PHP Codeigniter ,datamapper library.

Thank you!!!

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...` ?  But you should be using prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($u->exists())
{
 echo "Found" // Do something
}
else
{
 echo "Nothing found" //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just using **count()** function like this

```
...
$result = $u->query($sql);
$total_data = count($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $this->db->get();

For Codeigniter use $count = $result->num_rows(); // HERE IS YOUR COUNT

For OOP PHP use $count = $result->num_rows;
```